# Count(*) as inside a JOIN on SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have the following query for a report all is working fine, but I need to add a variable in the report that totals up the number of records for each record returned based off the number of records in the "manheim_auction_listings" record. I feel like it needs to be inside a join but everywhere I would the "COUNT(*) AS num_of_runs" it seems to make the whole query only return a single line with the count the total number of records in the query rather than all the lines with a variable num_of_runs with the number of "manheim_auction_listings" records for each CAR record.

```
SELECT products.client_id,
    clients.name AS client_name,
    manheim_auction_lanes.lane_number,
    manheim_auction_listings.sequence,
    manheim_auction_listings.gross_sale_price,
    products.asking_price,  products.asking_price_condition, 
    manheim_auctions.auction_date,
    manheim_auctions.auction_number,
    product_purchases.total_spent,
    product_purchases.purchase_price 
FROM manheim_auction_listings
    JOIN cars ON 
    cars.id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id 
    JOIN products ON 
     cars.product_id = products.id 
    JOIN product_purchases ON
     current_product_purchase_id = product_purchases.id
    JOIN manheim_auctions ON 
     manheim_auctions.id = manheim_auction_listings.manheim_auction_id 
    JOIN manheim_auction_lanes ON 
      manheim_auction_lanes.id = manheim_auction_listings.manheim_auction_lane_id 
    JOIN clients ON 
     clients.id = products.client_id 
     AND clients.id LIKE $P{LoggedInUserAttribute_ClientID} 
WHERE 
     manheim_auctions.auction_number = $P{SaleNumber} 
     AND manheim_auctions.`year` = $P{SaleYear} 
ORDER BY manheim_auction_lanes.lane_number DESC,
    manheim_auction_listings.sequence DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: There's a lot going on here. Could you reduce the query to a simpler one that still demonstrates the problem?  Ie with fewer tables?

Comment: By the variable you are using I take that you are using iReport, so, why don't you create this count on it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT products.client_id,
       clients.name AS client_name,
       manheim_auction_lanes.lane_number,
       manheim_auction_listings.sequence,
       manheim_auction_listings.gross_sale_price,
       num_of_runs,
       products.asking_price,  products.asking_price_condition,
       manheim_auctions.auction_date,
       manheim_auctions.auction_number,
       product_purchases.total_spent,
       product_purchases.purchase_price 
FROM ( SELECT manheim_auction_id AS manheim_auction_id,
              COUNT( manheim_auction_id ) AS num_of_runs
       FROM manheim_auction_listings
       GROUP BY manheim_auction_id
     ) AS num_of_runs_finder
JOIN manheim_auction_listings ON manheim_auction_listings.manheim_auction_id = num_of_runs.manheim_auction_id
JOIN cars ON cars.id = manheim_auction_listings.car_id
JOIN products ON cars.product_id = products.id
JOIN product_purchases ON current_product_purchase_id = product_purchases.id
JOIN manheim_auctions ON manheim_auctions.id = manheim_auction_listings.manheim_auction_id
JOIN manheim_auction_lanes ON manheim_auction_lanes.id = manheim_auction_listings.manheim_auction_lane_id
JOIN clients ON clients.id = products.client_id 
            AND clients.id LIKE $P{LoggedInUserAttribute_ClientID}
WHERE manheim_auctions.auction_number = $P{SaleNumber}
  AND manheim_auctions.`year` = $P{SaleYear} 
ORDER BY manheim_auction_lanes.lane_number DESC,
         manheim_auction_listings.sequence DESC
```

This works by joining your other tables to one that calculates the number of listings associated with each `manheim_auction_id`, effectively appending a `manheim_auction_id`'s count to each row where that `manheim_auction_id` occurs.

If `num_of_runs` is calculated on some other criteria, then please advsie me accordingly.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.